# Neural Network with 1500+ features cannot fit in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, logistic-regression, data-fitting

There are 1875 features in data, which are correlated with loan records of people. Some of them have been used for score card, ks=27.

I wanted to use these features in neural networks to determine whether a person is good or bad. However,it turned out all people were defined bad or good without selectivity, even I employed the method of'#imbalance data' (as shown in the following code).

Is there some problem in my code(activation function?),can someone give some tips? thanks in advance!

```
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

f=SAS7BDAT('data_10212102.sas7bdat')
data=f.to_data_frame()

#drop some time freatures
drop_cols = [col for col in data.columns if 'TIME' in col]
data=data.drop(drop_cols,axis=1)

data.loc[data.TARGET == 0,'Good'] =1
data.loc[data.TARGET == 1,'Good'] =0
data = data.rename(columns={'TARGET':'Bad'})

validation =data.ix[data.SETID==3,:]
train_test_data = data.loc[~data.index.isin(validation.index)]

X_train = train_test_data.ix[train_test_data.SETID==1,:]
X_test = train_test_data.ix[train_test_data.SETID==2,:]
X_train = shuffle(X_train)
X_test = shuffle(X_test)
X_validation = shuffle(validation)

Y_train = X_train.Bad
Y_train = pd.concat([Y_train,X_train.Good],axis=1)
Y_test = X_test.Bad
Y_test = pd.concat([Y_test,X_test.Good],axis=1)
Y_validation = X_validation.Bad
Y_validation = pd.concat([Y_validation,X_validation.Good],axis=1)

ratio = len(X_train)/len(X_train.ix[X_train.Bad==1,:])
X_train = X_train.drop(['Good','Bad'],axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop(['Good','Bad'],axis=1)
X_validation = X_validation.drop(['Good','Bad'],axis=1)

#imbalance data
Y_train.Bad *= ratio
Y_test.Bad *=ratio
Y_validation.Bad *= ratio

#parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 2000
batch_size = 512
display_step = 500

n_samples = X_train.shape[0]
n_features = 1845
n_class = 2

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_features])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_class])

n_units =2048
n_layers =7
W={}
b={}

for i in range(n_layers):

if i==0:
    W[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_features, n_units]))
    b[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_units]))
    pred = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W[i]) + b[i])

elif 0<i<n_layers-1:
    W[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_units, n_units]))
    b[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_units]))
    pred = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(pred, W[i]) + b[i])

else:
    W[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_units, n_class]))
    b[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_class]))
    pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(pred, W[i]) + b[i])

cost = -tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(pred))
optimizer = 
tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:

sess.run(init)

for epoch in range(training_epochs):

    avg_cost = 0

    total_batch = int(n_samples / batch_size)
    for i in range(total_batch):
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], 
                        feed_dict={x: X_train[i * batch_size : (i+1) * batch_size], 
                                   y: Y_train[i * batch_size : (i+1) * batch_size]
                                   })

        avg_cost = c / total_batch
    plt.plot(epoch+1, avg_cost, 'co')


    if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
        print("Epoch:", "%04d" % (epoch+1), "avg_cost=",avg_cost )
        print("Training Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: X_train, y:Y_train}))
        print("Testing Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: X_test, y:Y_test}))
        print("Validating Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: X_validation, y:Y_validation}))

        train_prob =pred.eval(feed_dict={x: X_train})
        train_predict=tf.argmax(train_prob,1).eval()
        print("train:",confusion_matrix(1-Y_train['Good'],train_predict))


        test_prob = pred.eval(feed_dict={x: X_test})
        test_predict=tf.argmax(test_prob,1).eval()
        print("test:",confusion_matrix(1-Y_test['Good'],test_predict))


        validation_prob = pred.eval(feed_dict={x: X_validation})
        validation_predict=tf.argmax(validation_prob,1).eval()
        print("validation:",confusion_matrix(1-Y_validation['Good'],validation_predict))

print("Optimization Finished!")

#Save the variables to disk
save_path = saver.save(sess,"./model_v0.ckpt")
print("Model saved in file: %s" %save_path)

plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.ylabel("Cost")
plt.show()
```

Comment: what do the two lines `data.loc[data.TARGET == 0,'Good'] =1` and `data.loc[data.TARGET == 1,'Good'] =0` do?

Comment: just for one-hot Encoding

Comment: do you one-hot encode 'Good' as zero and one?

Comment: In 'Good' column ,1 represents good people ,while 0 for bad.In 'Bad' column ,1 represents bad people ,while 1 for good.